# How does this query works

Tags: sql-server

```
select top 1 sal from(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 6 sal
FROM salary
ORDER BY sal desc) a order by sal
```

I am new to sql server can any one please tell me that how this query is finding the 6th highest
salary from table salary, i can understand that inner query is finding the top 6 salaries and arranging them in descending order, but the thing that i cannot understand is that top 1 should give the highest salary from the 6 salaries which are arranged in descending order how is it returning the last(bottom) salary

Comment: TOP is not the same as MAX. TOP goes by order.

Comment: how is top 1 finding the 6th highest it should find the highest salary  and what is the role of "a" in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `order by` at the end, it's ascending by default, which means get the lowest salary from the top 6 highest salaries.

`a` is required by SQL Server when we select from sub query. It makes no sense here.

A 'cleverer' query is

```
SELECT sal
FROM salary
ORDER BY sal
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

how do you know that inner query is returning top 6 salaries in descending order?

```
ORDER BY sal desc
```

The DESC keyword will arrange them in descending order....by default it orders by Ascending order. The outer query has an `ORDER BY` not `ORDER BY DESC`

Hence it returns the least salary among the top 6 salaries returned by inner query.